# Unusual LUA function syntax

Tags: lua

I'm a new LUA user, version 5.3 and I came across a function statement that is a bit confusing. I've tried to find some explanation in the reference manual but to no avail.

```
function myfunc.execute()
   print("Hello")
end
```

I don't understand this syntax. Does this mean to add ".execute()"?

Below is a example file that fails to print within the table myfunc.

```
local myfunc = {}
myfunc.version = "2.0"

function myfunc.execute()
   print("Hello World!")
end

return myfunc
```

When I run this i get no print out: "Hello World!". I'm trying to understand how lua works here when executing the above script in a file. Why does the print statement not work?

Comment: `myfunc` is a table, `execute` is a function located inside that table.

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Thanks for the insight. Could you have a look at the edited question and comment? Your input is appreciated.

Comment: @lhf Thanks for the link :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are simply defining the `execute` method that is in the `myfunc` table. Remove the `return myfunc` line and just call your function like this:

```
myfunc.execute()
```

There is nothing special about the `execute` word. It is not a Lua keyword. Its just the name you are giving to a function.